# Is it really true that ALL JPA entity class methods must not be final?

Tags: jpa

The JPA 2.1 specification says:

> The entity class must not be final. No methods or persistent instance variables of the entity class may be final.

Does "no methods" really mean every single method—`private`, `static`, `protected`, non-state-changing, etc.—in the entity class?  Or was this supposed to convey that only methods annotated with `@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)` are prohibited from being `final`?

I understand why entity classes cannot be `final`, and I understand why persistent instance variables of the entity class cannot be `final`.  I also understand why persistent property accessors and mutators cannot be `final`.

I don't understand why all other methods (ones that manipulate `transient` fields, for example, or that are stateless, or `static`, or `private`) cannot be `final`.

The best I can surmise is that the specification wanted to leave the door open for bytecode injection everywhere—e.g. perhaps my stateless method's invocation of a getter needs to have that invocation be rewritten to invoke some kind of JPA-provider-injected method instead.

This restriction of course makes it hard to reuse entity-like classes From Elsewhere as building blocks, since some of them may feature `final` methods, but are in every other way suitable for augmenting with an `orm.xml` and thereby for transforming into JPA entities.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is simply a bad formulation of the problem, meaning it is NOT EVERY method.

As a static method is not bound to a particular entity instance, it means it would be REALLY stupid to change/control the behavior of that static method. Imagine when it is called from a context that has nothing to do with persistence. So that's why I suppose that is a formulation error.

Related to other methods than accesors/mutators, I think it makes sense to not have them final, as it is really complicated to find out, whether a method accesses or not persistent data. If the method is private, that could still be a problem, as you could call it with reflection.

Also, as I remember I found another place in JPA 2.0 where it was ambiguous formulated, (and my tests have shown how to interpret it).

PS: of course this is only my opinion, and is not based on any articles or official documentation.